# Display List of array objects in highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Hope you all doing well :)
I have a question about displaying list of array objects in highchart.
Below is my data structure, as you can see this is a list of 5 array objects.

[image]

I want "name" to be my xAxis value and "y" to be my yAxis value.

```
series: [{
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: $scope.requiredData

         }]
```

It returns me a chart like this,
[image]

Can anyone help with that?

Many Thanks

Comment: `function (data) {

                    $scope.records = data;
                    $scope.requiredData = $scope.records.map(function (item) {
                        return [{name:item.act_title, y:item.session_seconds / 3600 || 0, drilldown:item.act_id}];
                 }); `
this is my data structure.

Comment: I think you want you answer as [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]

Comment: I think this is a problem: `return [{name:item.act_title, y:item.session_seconds / 3600 || 0, drilldown:item.act_id}];` ==> `return {name:item.act_title, y:item.session_seconds / 3600 || 0, drilldown:item.act_id};` (removed extra array).

Comment: @PawełFus yes, you are right!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please conver you array of objects as

```
var result = array.map(i=>([i.name,i.y]))
```

this will give you as [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]] format

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

incomeReportChart = new Chart(incGraphElem, {
    type: 'bar',

data: {
        labels: incomeData.labels,
        barThickness : 1,

datasets: [{
            label: incomeData.label[0],
            fontSize: "8",
            data: incomeData.income,
            backgroundColor : "#5B90C2",
            color: "#000000",
            borderWidth: 1
        },

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            barThickness : 5,
            ticks: {
                fontColor: '#454545',
                stepSize : 5000,
                beginAtZero : true
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            fontColor: '#454545',
            barThickness : 12,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]

    }
}
```

});

Here you need to just set label and data in datasets as per requirnment.